# Set constrains based on other constraints in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following UI:
[image]

There are 3 labels, an image view and their parent view (represented with grey color). If I would change the height of the parent view (represented with the red line), I want the labels and the image view height change as well, but keeping the same ratio between the heights. It can be done programmatically, but is it possible using purely the interface builder, and if it is, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the constraint as "equal height" then you can edit the constraint to set the multiplier property. By default it is `1`.

You may use a factor as in `1.2` or a ratio as in `1:2` or even like `123:320`.

To create the proportional distance from the 2 elements I found no nice way so what I do is add hidden separators with proportional dimensions to the super view and then set the distance between elements and separators to zero.

I would be happy to hear about a better solution for this though.

Comment: It works, but if I want to set the distance between the top of the Image View and the parent view to proportional to the height of the parent view, the question is the same: is that possible? Because there is no equal top space or something like that.

Comment: Edited to add the distance solution.